# How do I print date data with bash

Tags: bash, awk, substring

I have lines like this:

```
20141114 15:15:15;/xx/yy/zz.../bla_bla_bla_201411131512.xxx.yyy.....;....
```

I need date data on this line. I can do with awk for first date data (20141114):

```
awk '{print $1}'
```

How can I print second (`201411131512`) date value with `awk` or other way?

I need to print 8 number that start with `201` (just `20141113`).

Path is not static, sometimes it is `bla_bla_201`, sometimes `bla-bla-201`, sometimes `201_bla_bla`, etc...

Comment: Show more sample data, because now it looks very randomly placed in the line.

Comment: Data not static, thats why I need to find first 201 and print 201 and after 5 number -> 20141113

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
$ var="20141114 15:15:15;/xx/yy/zz.../bla_bla_bla_201411131512.xxx.yyy.....;...."
$ grep -oP '(?<!\d)201\d{5}' <<< "$var"
20141114
20141113
```

`(?<!\d)` negative lookbehind asserts that the match wouldn't be preceded by a digit.

Comment: @volkanasr note that if there's any other strings on the line that start with 201 followed by 5 digits then this solution will print them too. It will NOT just print the 2nd 201 string on the line as you said you wanted.

Comment: Ed, he wants all the date strings, not only the second.

Comment: @AvinashRaj no, he specifically said `How can I print second (201411131512) date value`. If he's happy with this answer though...

Comment: he says, "i know how to print the first but don't know how to print the second"? Seems, he wants to print the both.

Comment: I assumed he was just demonstrating what he did know how to do as a reference for what he wanted to do but didn't know how to - i.e. print the second one. Whether he wanted the first one too or not is irrelevant since he knows how to do that if he wants and this is about the possible third one, but in any case he very specifically asked for how to print the second one, not how to print all of them. If he's happy with that then that's fine but I just wanted to point out that's what he was getting with this solution since the difference wouldn't show up with the sample input he posted.

Comment: @volkanasr try all solutions on an input line that contains `20141114 15:15:15;/xx/yy/zz..6720112345..bla_201411131512.xxx.yyy..20112345..` and if you're happy with the result then you've probably got a working solution.

Comment: I need first date too but I can do it with awk print $1. So I don't need that anymore, this command print both. There is no 201 without two date.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the words containing `201` and `5` digits after it, then just `grep` for it together with a set of digits:

```
$ grep -Eo '201[0-9]{5}' file
20141114
20141113
```

or

```
grep -o '201[0-9]\{5\}'
```

`-o` makes the output be just the matched part of the line, not all the line.

---

If it happens to be the number in the file name indicated on the 2nd field based on `;` separation do:

```
IFS=";" read -r f1 f2 <<< "20141114 15:15:15;/xx/yy/zz.../bla_bla_bla_201411131512.xxx.yyy.....;"
$ echo $f2
/xx/yy/zz.../bla_bla_bla_201411131512.xxx.yyy.....
```

and then

```
$ basename "$f2" | grep -Eo '201[0-9]{5}'
20141113
```

`basename` shows the "file name", that is, everything after the last `/`. Then, we get the `5` digits that follow `201`.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ awk '{print gensub(/.*[^0-9](201[0-9]{5}).*/,"\\1","",$2)}' file
20141113
```

You need to include `[^0-9]` in the RE segment before `201` to avoid getting false matches in the middle of numbers like `6720112345`.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use grep or awk

I think the best way is to use bash parameter expansion

like this :

```
  my_date="20141114 15:15:15;/xx/yy/zz.../bla_bla_bla_201411131512.xxx.yyy.....;...."

  my_date="${my_date##*_}"            //trim from the head to the last '_'            
                                      my_date="201411131512.xxx.yyy.....;...." 
  my_date="${my_date%%.*}"            //trim from the tail to the last '.'
                                      my_date="201411131512"
  my_date="${my_date:0:8}"            //keep only the first 8 chars
                                      my_date="20141113"
```

for more about parameter expansion look here : [Bash Parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)

Answer (score 0):

This `gnu awk` (due to multiple characters in RS) may do:

```
awk -v RS="201" -F. 'NR==3{print RS$1}' file
201411131512
```